# How do I switch from VS Code's Python Extention to the Python installed on my computer?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have had this problem before, modules I install on my computer wouldn't show up in vs code. I asked around and found the answer: I was using VS Code's Python extension; but I forget how to replicate it.

Comment: you have to switch the interpreter. And if you have the good one set, you might have to restart vs code to get the new libraries

Comment: the Python extension has nothing to do with the Python execution, it is language server related (intellisense and such)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the bottom left (with a python file open) you should see the currently used python:

[image]

Click on that to get a list of python versions found where you can choose one.

Comment: thanks for the help!